# Get value of attribute in an option in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

My code:

```
<select class="form-control valid">
    <option isday="False" value="2">Value 1</option>
    <option isday="True" value="3">Value 2</option>
    <option isday="True" value="4">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

I need to get the value `isday`.

Comment: Is Jquery allowed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the attr with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128936/how-to-get-the-attr-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

First method, you must provide and ID to each.
You can use jQuery :

```
var value_of_isday = $('#your-id').attr('isday');
```

Or, you can use JavaScript :

```
var value_of_isday = document.getElementById('#your-id').getAttribute('isday');
```

Second method, you can use classes or tag names, but, you must know you can access a specific element with a certain class or a tag name by it's index (the first index is 0) :

```
var isday_of_first_element = document.getElementsByClassName('your-class')[0].getAttribute('isday'); //using class
var isday_of_last_element = document.getElementsByTagName('option')[document.getElementsByTagName('option').length - 1].getAttribute('isday'); //using tag name
// [0] = first element index, [1] = second element index,.....,[document.getElementsByClassName('your-class').length - 1] or [document.getElementsByTagName('tag-name').length - 1] = last element index
```

You can also use a loop through all options and get all isday values from each one :
let's say you have a `class="option"` for all of your option elements :

```
var Select=document.getElementsByClassName('option');
for (var i=0;i<Select.length;i++) {
    var isday_of_current_option=Select[i].getAttribute('isday');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this in plain javascript you could do as follow:

If you can add an Id to the select you can get it as this

```
var select = document.getElementById("yourSelect");

//Get selected
var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('isday');

//Get all
var y;
for (y = 0; y < select.length; y++) {
     var isDay = select.options[y].getAttribute('isday');
}
```

To get the options value by class

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("valid");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    if(elements[i].tagName === 'SELECT') {

        //Get selected
        var selectedOption = elements[i].options[elements[i].selectedIndex].getAttribute('isday');

        //Get all
        var y;
        for (y = 0; y < elements[i].length; y++) {
             var isDay = elements[i].options[y].getAttribute('isday');
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected option isday attribute, you can use

```
var isday = $('.valid option:selected').attr('isday');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected element by accessing it through an id in jquery:

```
<select class="form-control valid" id ="mySelect">
```

`var selectedValue = $('#mySelect').val();`

Answer (score 0):

**https://jsfiddle.net/jwpuaubx/**

```
$("#myControl").on('change',function(){
    var a=$("#myControl option:selected").attr("isday");
  alert(a);
});
```